# Generate two categorical variables with a chosen degree of association in R

Tags: r, simulation, categorical-data

I'd like to use R to generate two categorical variables (such as eye color and hair color, for instance) where I can specify the degree to which these two variables are associated. It doesn't really matter to me which levels of eye color would be associated with which levels of hair color, but just being able to specify an overall association, such as by specifying the odds ratio, is a requirement. Also, I know there are ways to do this for two normally distributed continuous variables using, for example, the `mvtnorm` package, so I could take that route and then choose cut points to make the variables categorical after the fact, but I don't want to do it that way if I can avoid it. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: apologies for not being clearer from the start, but what I'm really asking I suppose is whether or not there's a function anybody knows of in some R package that will do this in one or two lines.

Comment: IMO, this question arguably belongs on [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/) (ie, stats.SE), rather than here. This strikes me as more of an understand-the-ideas question than a how-to-program question.

Comment: I think I have a pretty decent understanding of the ideas behind it. Maybe not Fisher-esque, but pretty decent. This is more of an "I'd like to have a quick R solution suggested to me" question, so I thought Stack Overflow was better. My apologies if I am in error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can specify the odds ratios (and you also need to specify the baseline odds), you just convert them to probabilities and use `runif()`.

*Edit (I misunderstood the question)*: Take a look at the [bindata package](http://cran.fhcrc.org/web/packages/bindata/index.html).

---

If you like, here is a function I wrote that you can use to generate such data without the package.  It is rather clunky; it's intended to be self-explanatory rather than elegant or fast.

```
odds.to.probs <- function(odds){
  probs <- odds / (odds+1)
  return(probs)
}

get.correlated.binary.data <- function(N, odds.x.eq.0, odds.y.eq.0.x.eq.0, 
                                       odds.ratio){
  odds.y.eq.0.x.eq.1 <- odds.y.eq.0.x.eq.0*odds.ratio
  prob.x.eq.0        <- odds.to.probs(odds.x.eq.0)
  prob.y.eq.0.x.eq.0 <- odds.to.probs(odds.y.eq.0.x.eq.0)
  prob.y.eq.0.x.eq.1 <- odds.to.probs(odds.y.eq.0.x.eq.1)

  x <- ifelse(runif(N)<=prob.x.eq.0, 0, 1)
  y <- rep(NA, N)
  y <- ifelse(x==0, ifelse(runif(sum(x))<=prob.y.eq.0.x.eq.0,       0, 1), y)
  y <- ifelse(x==1, ifelse(runif( (N-sum(x)) )<=prob.y.eq.0.x.eq.1, 0, 1), y)

  dat <- data.frame(x=x, y=y)
  return(dat)
}

> set.seed(9)
> dat <- get.correlated.binary.data(30, 3, 1.5, -.03)
> table(dat)
   y
x    0  1
  0 10 13
  1  0  7
```

Comment: Yeah, this is pretty much what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome, @psychometriko. I also wrote a function that will allow you to generate these in one line (sorry about the delay, I was doing something else). There's no problem w/ using the package if you want; this just allows you not to. Also, this works differently from the package, that works from converting correlated normals (IIRC), whereas this works from odds & odds ratios.

Comment: @gung-ReinstateMonica I was just reading your solution and it seems very sleek. Any idea how I could do the same thing but with relative risk instead of odds ratio? I can add another question or we can have a chat if you'd like.

Comment: @mandella, the relative risk isn't meaningful without a base rate, eg: .02/.01 != .98/.49.  So just specify the base rate you're interested in & the relative risk, & then you have two proportions. You can convert those 2 proportions into an OR & solve.