# Does Matlab have something like R's bindata for correlated binary numbers?

Tags: r, matlab, binary, correlation

I am trying to find a command that would do the same as the R's [bindata](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bindata/bindata.pdf). It finds correlated binary numbers, I need it to generate data where the numbers are somehow correlated. Is there anything like this for Matlab?

**Example code in R**

```
require(bindata)

n<-10
m<-1000

flb<-function(p1,p2){
q1<-1-p1
q2<-1-p2

min(sqrt(p2*q1/(p1*q2)),sqrt(p1*q2/(p2*q1)))
}

p<-runif(n)
#p[p<0.01]<-0.1
q<-1-p

rhomax<-matrix(nrow=n,ncol=n)
for(i in 1:n){
    for(j in 1:n) {
        rhomax[i,j]<-flb(p[i],p[j])*0.75
    }
}
diag(rhomax)<-1
rbin<-rmvbin(margprob=p,bincorr=rhomax,m)
res<-unique(rbin)
```

Comment: You can just code such a function from scratch. I provide an algorithm in my answer here: [Generate two categorical variables with a chosen degree of association in r](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20330823//20330903#20330903). It's not that hard. Note, however, that that function works differently from the way `bindata` works. If you need, I can provide code for a function that dichotomizes two correlated normals instead.

Comment: @gung sure go on, I added a code provided by my instructor. Now I need to find how to do something like this with Matlab.

Comment: Sorry, I think this is going to be too much for me to do right now; it's a bit more involved than I thought at 1st. The gist of an algorithm that dichotomizes normals is to draw a point from an m dimensional multivariate normal w/ the required correlational structure. Then, for each dim, create a threshold q. If the point is <q on that dim, the obs takes the value 1, else 0. The trick is how to determine the correlational structure & thresholds. Unfortunately the continuous correlations won't necessarily equal the binary cors (see [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/3086//3135#3135)).

Comment: @gung would it be possible to reuse the R code somehow? My goal is to generate test data that is not just random like [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/602726/generation-of-random-multilinear-polynomials-for-testing-non-negativity-algori) generated with Mersenne Twister so the plan now is to create correlated numbers, not sure yet how big hurdle in Matlab.

Comment: You can explore the R code by typing the function name at the command prompt. Eg, `>rmvbin`, any functions that are coded in R will display. The 1st half is run time checks that can be ignored. The function calls other functions & they can be explored similarly.